# Style table row if columrow includes a name

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, sql

I have a stats table with `MySQL` input.

If a `<tr>` includes a certain name **Hulzense Boys**, then the table row needs to get background color of `#CCCCCC;`

**This is my code:**

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
        $team = array();
        $ctr = 1;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            echo "<table><tr><td class='nummer'>";
            echo $ctr++. '</td><td class="styled-td">';
            echo $row['Team']. '</td><td class="styled-td2">';
            echo $row['Gespeeld']. '</td><td class="styled-td2">';
            echo $row['Gewonnen']. '</td><td class="styled-td2">';
            echo $row['Gelijk']. '</td><td class="styled-td2">';
            echo $row['Verloren']. '</td><td class="styledPUNTEN-td">';
            echo $row['Punten']. '</td><td class="styled-td2">';
            echo $row['DPV']. '</td><td class="styled-td2">';
            echo $row['DPT']. '</td><td class="styled-td2">';
            echo $row['Verschil']. '</td><td class="styled-td2">';
            echo "</td></tr></table>";
            $team = $row['Team'];
            }
    }
```

**And this is my output tested:**
[image]

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
    if ($row['Team'] == 'Hulzense Boys') {

    }
```

Hope you can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
        $team = array();
        $ctr = 1;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $highlighted = $row['Team'] == "Hulzense Boys" ? "background-color:#ff0" : "";
            echo "<table><tr style=\"$highlighted\"><td class='nummer'>";
            echo $ctr++. '</td><td class="styled-td">';
            echo $row['Team']. '</td><td class="styled-td2">';
            echo $row['Gespeeld']. '</td><td class="styled-td2">';
            echo $row['Gewonnen']. '</td><td class="styled-td2">';
            echo $row['Gelijk']. '</td><td class="styled-td2">';
            echo $row['Verloren']. '</td><td class="styledPUNTEN-td">';
            echo $row['Punten']. '</td><td class="styled-td2">';
            echo $row['DPV']. '</td><td class="styled-td2">';
            echo $row['DPT']. '</td><td class="styled-td2">';
            echo $row['Verschil']. '</td><td class="styled-td2">';
            echo "</td></tr></table>";
            $team = $row['Team'];
            }
    }
```

Or assign a class name to `$highlighted` and use the class on the `tr` element.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: [Compare variables PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239766/compare-variables-php)

This should fix your problem.

Comment: Tried this: $myVar = $_GET['Hulzense Boys'];
 if (isset($myVar)) {
  echo "henkje";
 } but doesn't work

Comment: Than you'll need to do some debugging.


Check if your $row['team'] actually has a variable in it.


You can simply check this with an echo.

Answer (score 0):

use [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
if (strpos($row['Team'], 'Hulzense Boys') !== false) {

}
```

or case-insensitive one [stripos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strripos.php)

Comment: @AlexanderFT do you think case-sensitive ?

Comment: I used capitals where needed